# Implementing history tracking in SaveChanges override

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I am currently trying to implement history tracking on all of my tables in my app in a generic way by overriding the `SaveChanges` method and making use of reflection. As a simple case, let's say I have 2 classes/dbsets for my domain objects and a history table for each like the following:

```
DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
DbSet<CatHistory> CatHistories { get; set; }
DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
DbSet<DogHistory> DogHistories { get; set; }
```

The `CatHistory` class looks like the following (`DogHistory` follows the same scheme):

```
public class CatHistory : HistoricalEntity
{
  public int CatId { get; set; }

  public virtual Cat Cat{ get; set; }
}
```

My Goal is when an object is saved, I would like to insert a record in the appropriate history table. I am having trouble overcoming type difference when using reflection. My current attempt is below and I seem to be stuck on the `//TODO:` line:

```
        var properties = entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Where(x => entry.Property(x).IsModified).ToList();

        //get the history entry type from our calculated typeName
        var historyType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == historyTypeName);

        if(historyType != null)
        {

          //modified entries
          if (dbSet != null && historyDbSet != null && entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
          {
            var existingEntry = dbSet.Find(entry.Property("Id").CurrentValue);

            //create history record and add entry to table
            var newHistories = GetHistoricalEntities(existingEntry, type, entry);

            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { historyType });
            var typedHistories = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

            //TODO: turn newHistories (type = List<HistoricalEntity>) into specific list type (List<MyObjectHistory>) so I can addrange on appropriate DbSet (MDbSet<MyObjectHistory>)

            historyDbSet.AddRange(newHistories);
          }
        }
```

Comment: If you are looking to map from one entity to a 'historical' entity, try [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: I have a list of historical entities and im trying to map to a variable type. I'm pretty familiar with automapper and havent seen a way to do this

Comment: For all who may be interested in doing something like this, I felt it important to note that this implementation had pretty huge performance impacts in saving sizable amounts of data due to the amount of reflection that is being used and I'd suggest to stay away from it. Currently, check out sql server 2016 temporal tables as it's the cleanest implemel server 2016 or later as its the cleanest implementation of history tracking ive seen so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map your historical entities. I just created a little test, hopefully it replicates your situation:

```
IList dogs = new List<Dog>() { new Dog { Id = 1, Name = "Alsatian" }, new Dog { Id = 2, Name = "Westie" } };
var dogHistoryType = typeof(DogHistory);
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { dogHistoryType });
var typedHistories = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

mapper.Map(dogs, typedHistories);

foreach (var historyItem in typedHistories)
{
    this.Add(historyItem);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you're using `typedHistories[1] as FooHistory` and I won't necessarily know to cast the object as a `FooHistory`. There can't be any hard references to types in the code since the type is variable

Comment: Have edited the above to make it clearer (see commented line). Can you AddRange with an IList? It does at least compile, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: OK, we can use a foreach on the IList as just use `Add()` directly on the context. See above edit.

Comment: Thanks for the input- I am trying to work this into the solution and will get back to you (and will happily mark as accepted if this works for me)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain the way I have implemented in my application.

I have created Models with name ending **History** for models for which application needs to insert before deleting the record from the original table.

**BaseModel.cs**

```
namespace ProductVersionModel.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    /// <summary>
    /// all common properties of the tables are defined here
    /// </summary>
    public class BaseModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// id of the table
        /// </summary>
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// user id of the user who modified last 
        /// </summary>
        public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// last modified time
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime LastModifiedTime { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// record created user id
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// record creation time
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Not mapped to database, only for querying used
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public int RowNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
namespace ProductVersionModel.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    /// <summary>
    /// store detals of the product
    /// </summary>
    public class ProductStatus : BaseModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the product
        /// </summary>
        [Required, MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// product version validity start date
        /// </summary>

        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// product version valid till
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime? ValidTill { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This field used to keep track of history of a product
        /// </summary>
        public int ProductNumber { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**HistoryBaseModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ProductVersionModel.Model.History
{
    public class HistroyBaseModel
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// id of the table
        /// </summary>
        [Key,  DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string DeletedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DeletedTime { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// record created user id
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// record creation time
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ProductStatusHistory.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using ProductVersionModel.Model.History;

// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
namespace ProductVersionModel.Model.History
{
    public class ProductStatusHistory : HistroyBaseModel
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the product
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// product version validity start date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// product version valid till
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime? ValidTill { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This field used to keep track of history of a product
        /// </summary>
        public int ProductNumber { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In **Delete** method of your **CrudRepository**

```
    public virtual int Delete(List<object> ids, string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                var dbObject = _table.Find(id);
                HistroyBaseModel historyRecord = null;
                var modelAssembly = Assembly.Load(nameof(ProductVersionModel));
                var historyType =
                    modelAssembly.GetType(
                        // ReSharper disable once RedundantNameQualifier   - dont remove namespace it is required
                        $"{typeof(ProductVersionModel.Model.History.HistroyBaseModel).Namespace}.{typeof(TModel).Name}History");

                if (historyType != null)
                {
                    var historyObject = Activator.CreateInstance(historyType);

                    historyRecord = MapDeletingObjectToHistoyObject(dbObject, historyObject, userName);

                    DatabaseContext.Entry(historyRecord).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                DatabaseContext.Entry(dbObject).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            return DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            throw HandleDbException(ex);
        }
    }

    protected virtual HistroyBaseModel MapDeletingObjectToHistoyObject(object inputObject, object outputObject, string userName)
    {
        var historyRecord = MapObjectToObject(inputObject, outputObject) as HistroyBaseModel;
        if (historyRecord != null)
        {
            historyRecord.DeletedBy = userName;
            historyRecord.DeletedTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        return historyRecord;
    }

    protected virtual object MapObjectToObject(object inputObject, object outputObject)
    {
        var inputProperties = inputObject.GetType().GetProperties();
        var outputProperties = outputObject.GetType().GetProperties();//.Where(x => !x.HasAttribute<IgnoreMappingAttribute>());
        outputProperties.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var prop =
                inputProperties.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Name.Equals(x.Name) && y.PropertyType == x.PropertyType);
            if (prop != null)
                x.SetValue(outputObject, prop.GetValue(inputObject));
        });

        return outputObject;
    }
```

Where **TModel** is the type of the model

```
public class CrudRepository<TModel> : DataAccessBase, ICrudRepository<TModel> where TModel : class, new()
public class ProductStatusRepository : CrudRepository<ProductStatus>, IProductStatusRepository
```

You can override methods **MapDeletingObjectToHistoyObject** and **MapObjectToObject** in your related repository if you want to map complex entitites like child element list.